# Black Holes, New Branes and Stars

Tags: astrophysics

Could a dying star in one brane ( assuming that we live in a world of multiple branes { not a Randal-Sumdrum model of a single brane}) be the start of the birth of the star ( more precisely Super Nova) in another brane? If so is the black hole merely the "Shadow" of the star's gravity in another brane ( because gravity is not confined to a single brane) ? Could it be that as the black hole eventually dies in one brane it becomes stronger in another (as the star keeps traveling further away from the "origin brane { assuming the number of branes are infinite}) ? That means the star never "actually" dies right? but what happens when the black hole grows to big and becomes a "Black Pancake"? Could this be true in any way?

Comment: ... "astrophysics" ? LOL :-D

Answer (score 1):

If dark matter were capable of clumping up into stars, it would have to have sufficient friction to make its own galactic disk, and we would see the effects astronomically, in that the distribution of dark matter would not by uniform around the galaxy, but flattened out in a pancake along the same plane as the galaxy. The reason is that gravitational interactions between the dark-matter stars and the ordinary matter stars would lead to an effective friction between the two, sharing their angular momentum and energy.

The result would be stuff we don't see, including dark-matter stars showing up in lensing surveys, occasional dark-matter ordinary-matter binaries, and rotation curves for galaxies that reveal a large disk-confined dark-matter distribution.

Further, the idea that alternate branes are sufficiently far away to make separate universes interacting only gravitationally is very disfavored by current data. This idea requires the extra dimensions to be large, to allow localization of the quantum particles to our brane. Large extra dimensions push the Planck scale down, and we know that the Planck scale is high, from the low neutrino masses, but also from proton decay, lack of strong CP violations, and electroweak precision data. See this answer: [Can black holes be created on a miniature scale?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22578/can-black-holes-be-created-on-a-miniature-scale/22601#22601) .

The remainder of your question is confused about black holes--- the black holes cannot be confined to one brane--- they are purely gravitational and are not stuck to branes. If they are stellar black holes, they would stretch from one brane to the other, and appear as equal mass black holes on both.