# How possible is it that the Large Hadron Collider (LHC) on its second try, could disrupt the gravity of Earth?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, large-hadron-collider

Is it possible that the [Large Hadron Collider],with a possible slight change in speed (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Hadron_Collider),could disrupt the gravity of Earth?

Comment: Why/how do you think it would do that?

Comment: Possibly related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22578

Comment: As with all these (pop-sci plausible) suggestions, if there was any truth to it the Big Particle Accelerator in the Sky would have done this to us long, long ago. SO relax.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot disrupt the gravity of the Earth.  There are other infinitesimal possibilities of doomsday scenarios though these stories have been debunked many [times](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_of_high-energy_particle_collision_experiments).

> The report ruled out any doomsday scenario at the LHC, noting that the physical conditions and collision events which exist in the LHC, RHIC and other experiments occur naturally and routinely in the universe without hazardous consequences,[3] including ultra-high-energy cosmic rays observed to impact Earth with energies far higher than those in any man-made collider.