# Are experiments being conducted towards the creation of micro black holes?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes, accelerator-physics

Apparently, *there could be a way for our own particle colliders to create very transient black holes*, if some things about the universe are true (as far as I understand, those have to do with the number of dimensions necessary for a micro black hole to be possible). It seems like good research: you **prove** they are possible and understand them better, and maybe prove other spatial dimensions along the way, or you can't make the current prediction model work and you look for **an alternative**.

Of course, I know nothing about how hard it is to conduct such experiments and to come up with them. I may be being foolish.

Note that I am talking about **experimentation**, not theory: is it possible to conduct a series of experiments culminating in one that would say something about micro black holes? I believe we have nothing to lose no matter what's the conclusion. **Experimental data** is the most valued form of data, if one can say I've been reasonably well taught.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can black holes be created on a miniature scale?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22578/can-black-holes-be-created-on-a-miniature-scale)

Comment: Maybe not... You see, I wanted an answer to this question: can we experiment with that? Not counter-theories. Let's say my question is a mere hypothetical: considering the theory is still up to debate, is it possible to conduct a series of experiments culminating in one that would say something about micro black holes? We could gain a lot from such research (one way or another, research and experimentation is always good).