# Can we create black holes in modern particle accelerators?

Tags: particle-physics, black-holes, particle-accelerators

The question is if modern particle accelerators (or cosmic rays for that matter) can create black holes. Has those events been detected? If not, how far are we in terms of orders of magnitude energy?
Bonus question: is creating black holes scientifically interesting?

I've read [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22578/can-black-holes-be-created-on-a-miniature-scale), but the accepted answer is about string theory and politics. My question is about energies and devices required.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can black holes be created on a miniature scale?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22578/)

Comment: @JohnRennie no, I mentioned that question in my question. Discussion went towards string theory and politics that time, probably because the news seven years ago.

My question was answered here, also it's answered in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [Micro black hole - Minimum mass of a black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_black_hole#Minimum_mass_of_a_black_hole):

> In principle, a black hole can have any mass equal to or above
> about $2.2\times 10^{−8}$ kg or $22$ micrograms (the Planck mass).

Given this Planck mass (or the corresponding Planck energy $1.2\times 10^{19}$ GeV)
it is far out of reach with any human particle accelerator technology.

Comment: Wikipedia page you've linked also provides a paragraph on human-made micro black holes, thank you.

Comment: Please note that LHC experiments still check the large extra dimensions model of string theories, where micro black holes are expected (despite the planck limit in your answer)  Here are limits from one experiment  in the latest data  "In  the  context  of  models  with  large  extra  dimensions,semiclassical black holes with minimum masses as high as 10.1 TeV and string balls with masses as high as 9.5 TeV are excluded by this search ".  https://cds.cern.ch/record/2318378/files/scoap3-fulltext.pdf